# Binding HTML5 audio listening event, jQuery .ajax() and .html() functions

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to achieve the following effect: I have an HTML5 audio element using mediaelement.js with a playlist. I would like to activate a server query on every change of track (play, next etc.). I am using the HTML5 "playing" event, so far so good. I am sending an attribute of the current audio tag (src in my case) to a PHP script via AJAX and it is working ok, but I would like to put the HTML result from meta.php into a div in the page.

Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("audio#mejs").on('playing',function(){
    var source = $('#mejs').attr('src');
    $.ajax({
        url: "meta.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: "a=" + source,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#nowPlaying').html(data);
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

The HTML elements are directly in the body tag:

```
<audio id="mejs" type="audio/mp3" width="600" height="64" src="http://"></audio>
<div id="#nowPlaying"></div>
```

I think I am missing something fundamental, I am quite new to JS/jQuery. Everything is working as intended except the .html() method does nothing.. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Is your `<div>` id really the 11-character sequence `#nowPlaying`, or is it the 10-character sequence `nowPlaying`?

Comment: Nothing in the console except GET 200 OK from the meta.php.
The ID is OK, I've spent an hour copying and pasting it :)

Comment: 11 characters! I am embarrassed... it was the hash in the ID.... Thank you very much, my first post here was for a lame and stupid thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML should be

```
<div id="nowPlaying"></div>
```

instead of

```
<div id="#nowPlaying"></div>
```

The selector invocation `$('#nowPlaying')` selects the element whose id is `nowPlaying`, not one with an id of `#nowPlaying`.